# Cannot await fs.appendFile

Tags: node.js

I am trying to check if all of my required environment variables are present before I start my Nodejs server and terminate Nodejs if there are some or all variables missing.

So I have a module named `checkVariables.js`:

```
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.appendFile)

checkDBState()

async function checkDBState(){
    try{
        dbState = process.env.dbState
        if(!dbState){
            console.log(`dbState not Found in the .env file`)
            console.log(`Terminating Server`)
            await errorLogOnFile(`dbState not Found in the .env file`)
            return false
         }
         return true
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}

async function errorLogOnFile(errorMessage){
    try{
        let currentDate = new Date()

        let dateTime = currentDate.getMonth()+1 + "/"
        + (currentDate.getDate()+1)  + "/" 
        + currentDate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
        + currentDate.getHours() + ":"  
        + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" 
        + currentDate.getSeconds(); 
    
        errorMessage = `\n${dateTime} - ${errorMessage} `
        
        await writeFile('errorLog.txt',errorMessage)
        process.exit(1);
        // fs.appendFileSync('errorLog.txt',errorMessage,(err)=>{
        //     if(err) throw err;
        //     process.exit(1);
        // })
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    } 
   
   
}
```

The problem I am seeing is that the code is not awaiting to writefile and some other modules run while the process is writing to file. Because of this I am getting some errors on other files before the server is terminated. I used the debugger and found out that the entire process is synchronous until it reaches `writeFile`. How is this possible when I am clearly asking it to await before moving on?

Comment: *"I am getting some errors on other files"* - What exactly is causing the error?  In the code shown you do indeed await `writeFile`, and await `errorLogOnFile`, but do not await `checkDBState`.  If you have another operation not shown here which executes immediately after this code and depends on this code finishing then it would need to be in a `.then()` on the call to `checkDBState`.  Also, what is `util.promisify`?  Can you perhaps provide a complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: The error I am getting is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dbState' of undefined` on other files because the I removed the dbState from my env varaible for testing.  I know that Nodejs loads its module synchronously, so I have placed this module at the top of my `app.js` file and tried to make everything synchronous in the file so that if there is an error the server shuts down.

Comment: The util.promisify() method defines in utilities module of Node.js standard library. It is basically used to convert a method that returns responses using a callback function to return responses in a promise object.

Comment: So, `await` ONLY blocks your current function.  It does not block the event loop so lots of other things can still run.  Is that what is causing your problem - that other things are running during the `await`?

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, what do you think about this solution?

```
async function checkDBState() {
   dbState = process.env.dbState;
   if(!dbState){
     await new Promise((resolve) => {
        let currentDate = new Date();

        let dateTime = currentDate.getMonth()+1 + "/"
        + (currentDate.getDate()+1)  + "/" 
        + currentDate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
        + currentDate.getHours() + ":"  
        + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" 
        + currentDate.getSeconds(); 

        errorMessage = `\n${dateTime} - ${errorMessage} `;
        fs.appendFileSync('errorLog.txt',errorMessage);
        resolve(console.log('file written'));        
     });
  }
  console.log('this happens after file is written');
}

checkDBState();
```

The output will be (`if(!dbState) === true`):

```
file written
this happens after file is written
```

And in the end a golden rule that helped me thousand times: **Async/Await only works on functions that return (and resolve) a promise**

Comment: Your golden rule is used by most linters out there so there should be no problem spotting it :)

Comment: I don't know how the golden rule applies to the original question.  The `writeFile()` function does return and resolve a promise so it is appropriate to use `await` on it.  That was not the OP's issue at all.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I tried this but it still does not await. Maybe Nodejs modules when we use `require` does not load from top to bottom synchronously as I thought. It is running the second module while the first module has not finished.